# Django: How do you force an app to use a non-default database from the settings.py?

Tags: django

Django can make use of multiple database engines at the same time. My problem is the queries always refer to the default database. I want the queries for a different app to go to a different database instead of the default database.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django supports multiple databases and you can use the "[Automatic database routing](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing)" to do what you want.

I think that it's enough powerful for your needs but if you need more flexibility, you can "[Manually selecting a database](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database)"